# Alternative to subversion / TortoiseSVN on Win xp?

Tags: version-control

I'm looking for an alternative version control software to TortoiseSVN/ Subversion. Only interested in those with a GUI and an easy installation process, though if multiple installations are needed (Such as vault, which needs both a client, server, and lots of other stuff), please give some installation instructions with your answer.

I'm a one man shop as of right now.

Comment: Out of interest what is the issue with svn?

Comment: Why did this receive a -1? @reqsuare, I just want to try something different than svn. No actual issues except perhaps that tortoisesvn's ui is soometimes annoying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Mercurial and TortoiseHg](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TortoiseHg).

Comment: I can't stand TortoiseHg's interface. It's dreadful compared to TortoiseSVN. I'd rather use the command line.

Comment: These are subjective points. Mercurial has a GUI and an easy installation process - and while I agree that TortoiseSVN is much slicker than TortoiseHg, the latter seems perfectly usable to me.

Answer (score 2):

Just as matter of interest why is it that you dont want to use subversion?
If you dont want to look after the subversion server and repos, you can always put them in places like [assembla](http://assembla.com), or similar(i only used them and pretty happy wit the service and the value) , that for a small fee will look after all that and the integration with trac, etc.
And the integration tools with most IDEs are pretty good.

Other option is git, tho integration with windows is not great and this is something that you seem to be very interested in.

(I m not afiliated with assembla, just a happy customer so far)

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested in why you don't like SVN, but some alternatives that I have some experienve with and are free (atleast for one man shops):

- [CVS](http://www.march-hare.com/cvspro/)
- [Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/)
- [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/)

I like Perforce when in an environment with a lot of users (but then it starts costing serious money), but for my personal (one man) stuff, I use SVN - it's much easier to administer.

Answer (score 1):

I second Bazaar -- I've recently been part of converting two teams to using it and it's been quite easy.  (Think of it being like `git`, but able to work in the same way you're used to doing with `svn`, plus able to work on Windows.)  Two people in my office are using TortiseBZR on Windows with good success.  It's easy to set up a server too -- I had it done in less than 30 minutes and able to work with others.  (The easiest/quickest way to do a server is over SFTP, but you can do it all on your machine too, if you'd like.)

Answer (score 0):

I use GIT on windows with [TortoiseGIT](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) and i'm loving it! .

Comment: Where can i find some tutorials or such on git for basic functions such as creating a repository, importing files/checking out, committing, etc/

Comment: these are more terminal based but gitcasts.com gives a great introduction to git

Answer (score 0):

[Git Extenions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) looks like a better way of using Git in Windows than the alternatives. It even comes with a Visual Studio plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com) integrates directly into Visual Studio if you are working on the .net Framework. The developers of Stack Overflow [used it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)!

PS: Its not free